# Infinite Carousel Clunky....at first

Tags: jquery, infinite-carousel

The jQuery infinite carousel works, but its jumpy. Upon clicking to 'scroll right', it leaps forward, then resets to its starting position. It then works normally for each click to scroll right after that. When one clicks the 'left scroll arrow', it moves smoothly, but the 'infinite' aspect is broken: it scrolls, leaving a blank space, then replaces the blank space with the proper image. This happens in all browsers.

**Question:** Would the wrong margins or carousel container width make it behave like this? If not, what does cause it?

HTML

```
<div id='carousel_container'>
  <div id='left_scroll'><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/left.png' /></div>
  <div id='carousel_inner'>
        <ul id='carousel_ul'>
            <li class="shadow"><a href="videos"><h1>Video</h1><div id="youtubeThumb"><object width="314" height="206"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/3aVnkBRcXEg?version=3&autoplay=1&loop=1&3aVnkBRcXEg&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/3aVnkBRcXEg?version=3&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=3aVnkBRcXEg&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="314" height="206" allowscriptaccess="always" ></embed></object></div></a></li>
            <li class="shadow"><a href="testimonials"><h1>Testimonials</h1><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/FeatureBlockTestimonials2.jpg' /></a></li>
            <li class="shadow"><a href="posts/category/news"><h1>News</h1><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/newsThumb1.jpg' /></a></li>
            <li class="shadow"><a href="gallery"><h1>Gallery</h1><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/GalleryThumb2.jpg' /></a></li>


            <li class="shadow"><a href="posts/category/for-sale/"><h1>For Sale</h1><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/saleThumb1.jpg' /></a></li>
            <li class="shadow"><a href="posts/category/finished-hemis"><h1>Finished HEMI's</h1><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/finishedThumb1.jpg' /></a></li>
            <li class="shadow"><a href="posts/category/projects/"><h1>Projects</h1><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/projectThumb1.jpg' /></a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='right_scroll'><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/right.png' /></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        //move he last list item before the first item. The purpose of this is if the user clicks to slide left he will be able to see the last item
        $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'))

        //when user clicks the image for sliding right
        $('#right_scroll img').click(function(){

            //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '
            var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 52;

            //calculate the new left indent of the unordered list
            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;

            //make the sliding effect using jquery's anumate function '
            $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    

                //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '
                $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first'));

                //and get the left indent to the default -210px
                $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-0px'});
            }); 
        });

        //when user clicks the image for sliding left
        $('#left_scroll img').click(function(){
            var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 52;

            /* same as for sliding right except that it's current left indent + the item width (for the sliding right it's - item_width) */
            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + item_width;
            $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    

            /* when sliding to left we are moving the last item before the first list item */            
            $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last')); 

            /* and again, when we make that change we are setting the left indent of our unordered list to the default -210px */
            $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-0px'});
            });
        });
  });
```

CSS

```
/*CAROUSEL*/

#carousel_container{
    width:1190px;
    height:220px;
    margin-left:-110px;
}


#carousel_inner {
float:left; /* important for inline positioning */
width:1098px; /* important (this width = width of list item(including margin) * items shown */
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;  /* important (hide the items outside the div) */
/* non-important styling bellow */
/*background: #F0F0F0;*/
}

#carousel_ul {
position:relative;
left:-368px; /* important (this should be negative number of list items width(including margin) */
list-style-type: none; /* removing the default styling for unordered list items */
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width:2562px; /* important */
/* non-important styling bellow */
padding-bottom:10px;
}

#carousel_ul li{
float: left; /* important for inline positioning of the list items */
width:314px;  /* fixed width, important */
/* just styling bellow*/
padding:0px;
height:218px;
background:url('images/repeatingContentBG1.png') repeat;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:26px;
margin-right:26px;
}

#carousel_ul li img {
.margin-bottom:-4px; /* IE is making a 4px gap bellow an image inside of an anchor (<a href...>) so this is to fix that*/
/* styling */
cursor:pointer;
cursor: hand;
border:0px;
margin-top:-25px;
z-index:99;
}

#carousel_ul li h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:9999;
    position:relative;
    font-family:impact;
}
#left_scroll, #right_scroll{
float:left;
height:96px;
width:94px;
margin-top:60px;
/*background: #C0C0C0;*/
}
#left_scroll{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: -60px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1999;
}

#right_scroll{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1999;
    margin-left:-58px;
    margin-top:65px;
}

#left_scroll, #right_scroll a:hover{
    top:5px;
}

#left_scroll img, #right_scroll img{
/*styling*/
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
}

#youtubeThumb {
    width:314px;
    height:187px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix your title and fix your silly-looking "\*\*EDIT" lines.  They actually **are** scaring off people from your question.

Comment: If you use left floating div's instead, you don't have to worry about positioning at all. I cant figure out how you built your carousel, but I think the problem is in your jQuery considering the behavior.